# Unable to use regex in VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm having a PuTTY log file where output of all SSH session is captured. I want read that log file and break its content in desired form. 
In log file there is desired pattern for every ping command i have made.

I want output in .CSV file containing Date, Time, IP and STATUS as headers and data from log file. Content of log file is shown below:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2018.11.19 07:47:18 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "admin".
PING 172.27.1.4 (172.27.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.27.1.4: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.1.4: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
--- 172.27.1.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.058/1.139/1.221/0.088 ms
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2018.11.19 07:47:22 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "admin".
PING 172.27.1.5 (172.27.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.27.1.5: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.1.5: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
--- 172.27.1.5 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.041/1.061/1.081/0.020 ms 
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2018.11.19 07:47:26 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "admin".
PING 172.27.1.6 (172.27.1.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.27.1.6 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.27.1.6 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 172.27.1.6 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1004ms pipe 2
```

For every IP entire data will be found in `=~=~=~` and `---`.
If it found TTL then status will be healthy, and "Destination Host Unreachable" or "request timed out" then status will be Unhealthy.

A sample VBScript is written but it is listing only first value of log file.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f=fso.opentextfile("log.txt",1)
a = f.ReadAll
Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Multiline = True
r.IgnoreCase = True
r.Pattern = "=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log ((.|\n)*?)---"

Set Matches = r.Execute(a)
If Matches.Count > 0 Then Data = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
MsgBox Data
WriteFileText "Test.txt", Data
f.Close

Function WriteFileText(sFile, Data)
    Dim objFSO, oTS, sText
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oTS = objFSO.CreateTextFile(sFile, 2)
    oTS.WriteLine Data
    oTS.Close
    Set oTS = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What is your question? The title says that you're unable to use a regex - what is the problem you're running into? Please show how you're using the regex and what kind of error you're facing with it. Provide, if possible, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sir, i'm unable to get desired result as expected and want to have my output in same format as I have asked above. I have tried but failed to achieve the result. Highly appreciable if you help me to get result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting only the first match because you're processing only the first match:

```
Set Matches = r.Execute(a)
If Matches.Count > 0 Then Data = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
MsgBox Data
WriteFileText "Test.txt", Data
```

Change that code into a loop and it should do what you want:

```
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(sFile, 2)
For Each m In r.Execute(a)
    f.WriteLine m.SubMatches(0)
Next
f.Close
```

Adding a nested check for the "unhealthy" substrings inside the fragments will enable you to output a status "healthy" or "not healthy".

```
Set re2 = New RegExp
re2.Pattern = "destination host Unreachable|request timed out"
re2.IgnoreCase = True

If re2.Test(m.SubMatches(0)) Then
    WScript.Echo "Unhealthy"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Healthy"
End If
```

Alternatively check for `ttl=\d+` and report "healthy" when you find a match and "unhealthy" otherwise.